# Customizable pages for different audiences, Communities configuration

Tags: community, winter18

Is there any possible way of adding a different CSS for different Branding Sets? I'm asking about this new feature from 18' release, Dynamic Branding. From what I can see we can only edit standard branding options like font color, but the CSS is common for every set.

Specifically I'm trying to make some Navigation Menu items visible only for specific users and the only workaround I found is the CSS modification for groups of users. Maybe someone new better solution for that?

Thanks!